# jQuery UI button url

Tags: jquery-ui

Im using a jQuery UI button and I want to point it to specific url.
How is that possible?

```
<button>Button</button>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "input[type=submit], button" )
.button()
.click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: which jquery ui control you are using..and what you want only redirecting ?

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<button id="btYourButton">Button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#btYourButton" ).button().click(function( event ) {
            window.location = "http://google.com"
        });
    });
</script>
```